# CakePHP 3.0 Auth Component - Form Login with Email/Pass instead of Username/Pass

Tags: authentication, authorization, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.0, and I'm trying to get the Auth Component to use Email/Password for credentials instead of a Username/Password. In 2.x I believe there needed to be some type of code for the controller and both a username and email had to be present in the database. Anyways, here's my relevant code, I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. This is my first app written in 3.0, so I'm still transitioning from 2.x. Thanks!

/* AppController.php */

```
public $components = [
    'Flash',
    'Auth' => [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'dashboard',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'authorize' => ['controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
            ]
        ] 
    ]
];

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['group_id']) && $user['group_id'] == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view']);
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', ['Form']);
}
```

/* UsersController */

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);
}

public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'basic';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}


public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}




    /* login.ctp */

<div class="login">
<h1>Rising Tide Team Login</h1>
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username', ['label' => 'Username/Email']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end('authenticate') ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get what kind of problem or error you got, but I have noticed few things in your code.

- In AppController.php, you need to capitalize the `controller` of `'authorize' => ['controller'],` otherwise you will get an internal error.
- In login.ctp, you should not pass `'username'` to `$this->Form->input` but instead you should pass `email` since you want to authenticate user with email and password.